# MS ACCESS VBA as user for save as path

Tags: vba, ms-access

By default the following code sends the exported file to *My Documents*:

```
Public Sub cmdExport_Click()

    Application.ExportXML ObjectType:=acExportQuery, _
        DataSource:="export1", DataTarget:="whatever.xml"

End Sub
```

Is it possible to ask the user for a file path or dynamically set it to his/her desktop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the FilDialog object to let the user pick a file path/file name where ever/of whatever they want. Using this requires a reference to `Microsoft Office XX.0 Object Library` (well I think it is really only required if you want to use the `Office.MsoFileDialogType` constants where `msoFileDialogSaveAs = 2`)

```
Dim oDialog As FileDialog
Set oDialog = FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
oDialog.InitialFileName = "whatever.xml"
oDialog.Show
If oDialog.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
    Dim savePath As String
    savePath = oDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    Application.ExportXML ObjectType:=acExportQuery, DataSource:="export1", DataTarget:=savePath 
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub cmdExport_Click()

    Application.ExportXML ObjectType:=acExportQuery, DataSource:="export1", DataTarget:=currentproject.path & "whatever.xml"

End Sub
```

This would probably save it into the file of the current project.
Concerning the desktop, you may do it like  this:

```
Public Sub cmdExport_Click()

    Application.ExportXML ObjectType:=acExportQuery, DataSource:="export1", DataTarget:="C:\Users\" & environ("Username") & "\Desktop\"&"whatever.xml"

End Sub
```

But it would not always work well. E.g., if the main drive is not C:, or the windows is somehow else installed.